# php clickable image inside form with get resulting in x-y coordinates

Tags: php

I have created some code to make buttons clickable and return a value. 
When I click on the image in the browser the querystring is showing the x-y coordinates of the image I am currently in, while it should put the name of the image in the querystring.

I also replaced the "value" value to "test" just to check if it works but I still get x-y coordinates.

```
<?php
$dirname = "images_fotoviewer/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
foreach($images as $image){    
    echo "<form action='24_fotoviewer.php' method='GET'>";
    echo "<input type='image' src='" . $image . "' name='foto' value='" . $image . "'/>";
    echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

This is the querystring I get:

```
iwp1_basis_php/24_fotoviewer.php?foto.x=164&foto.y=48
```

Could someone help me to get the name of the image in the querystring?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you realize that you've a missing closing form tag.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have added the form closing tag and the query string in the question.

Comment: you'd need to pass a value from a GET array. Something like `$var = $_GET['foto'];` I tend to think. Or, use a hidden attribute, could work.

Comment: or instead of `name='foto'` try `name='" . $image . "'` if that's the goal here. Hold on.... I have another idea. what result are you looking to have? if you're looking to get rid of the x-y coordinates, I doubt that can be done. Image inputs always show those.

Comment: you've an answer below now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use input type="image" you will get a submitbutton as an image. It is default behaviour to send the x/y coordinates where you clicked it.

So to get the behaviour you want to try this:

1. Replace the form with an hyperlink (a href=...)
2. Create a hyperlink that contains the name of the image

Something like this:

```
<?php
foreach($images as $image){
?>
<a href="24_fotoviewer.php?imgName=<?php echo urlencode($image); ?>">
<img src=<?php echo $image; ?>
</a>
<?php
}
?>
```